Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance
I am running the following to schedule a CSV export daily:
DECLARE @sqlcmd VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @servername NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @instancename NVARCHAR(128);

-- Get the server name
SET @servername = @@SERVERNAME;

-- Get the instance name (it might be empty)
SET @instancename = COALESCE(@@SERVICENAME, '');

-- Print server and instance name for debugging
PRINT 'Server Name: ' + @@servername;
PRINT 'Instance Name: ' + @@servicename;

-- Construct the sqlcmd command
SET @sqlcmd = 'sqlcmd -S "' + @servername + '\' + @instancename + '" -d master -Q "SELECT * FROM vw_odbc_appts_InsuranceOrder ORDER BY CreatedAt ASC" -o "c:\csv\test.txt" -s ","';

-- Print the final command for debugging
PRINT 'SQLCMD Command: ' + @sqlcmd;

-- Execute the command
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sqlcmd;

But I keep getting this error:

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Any ideas on how to get past this?
I tried multiple things around the server name and instance name

What happens when you copy the sqlcmd output, log directly into the SQL Server and  and run it in a cmd window? Have you tried localhost instead? Not if there is no instance your serevrname will have a trailing \ . Maybe this is the problem? I suggest you copy/paste the output to the question (after changing server names)

Aside... why are you putting application objects in the master database instead of a user database of your own creation? Do you enjoy the special difficulties of restoring a failed master database from backups?

Is the SQL Browser service installed and running on the target server? It doesn't even exist on SQL Server for Linux installations, nor in mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server Docker containers. Is SQL Browser service's udp/1434 port accessible via firewall rules?
